# wifi router to cover multiple floors, and range extender capability

Tags: wifi

A split level ranch house, with main floor above ground and finished basement below grade and two bay attached garage.  An ADT type wifi doorbell camera and driveway (garage) wifi camera was installed, but the position of the frontier provided wifi router mostly on the other side of the house is not capable of connecting the driveway wifi camera.

I believe the wifi camera and doorbell is 802.11ac.  Late model phones and tablets are in use in the house, but nothing that is wifi6.

what is a good wifi router to choose. What would provide good wifi signal, to two floors, and provide good enough range, preferably so range extenders are not needed although would be nice if the router had range extension capability?  Should I just invest in *wifi6 mesh* ?

Comment: I am personally not a big fan of mesh, but that is an option. What I reccomend is have a normal (wifi or no wifi) router and use cat6 cables to the places you need wifi and put a wifi access point there. My school uses this method and it's really stable

Comment: for anyone interested i went with TPLink Deco S4, 3-pack amazon $65 on sale, only needed 2.  Got everything working and great wifi signal coverage.  The Deco S4 FAQ says you can mesh up a lot of access points but recommend no more than 10, so if I needed more than the 3 I have now I would just buy a whole other 3 pack.  Youtube vids show how to go about installation.